# A pointer to a std::promise causing problems

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm getting the following error

```
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
    *ptr->set_value(true);
make: *** [make] Error 1
```

from the this code

```
std::vector<std::promise<bool>*> prs;

void xyz(){
    std::promise<bool> pr;  
    prs.push_back(&pr); 
    std::future<bool> f = pr.get_future();  
    bool result = f.get();
}

void foo(void){
    std::thread t(xyz);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
    for(std::promise<bool>* ptr: prs){
        *ptr->set_value(true); 
    }
    t.join();
}

int main(void){
    foo();  
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that "void value not ignored" usually means that you are trying to use a void value where it isn't appropriate but I can't see that in this example.

Comment: Taking the address `&pr` is just completely unworkable.

Comment: (But syntactically you would just want `ptr->set_value(true);`.)

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks, problem solved. Rather than using &pr I used std::promise<bool>* pr = new std::promise<bool>(); so I can pass the pointer directly and then removing the * did the trick. cool.

Comment: Oh god oh god... (this is guaranteed not to be your last problem).

Comment: Accessing `std::vector` like this is not thread safe...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `*ptr->set_value(true)`.

The precedence rules for C++ make this statement `*(ptr->set_value(true))`.

`set_value()` returns `void`. You cannot deference `void`.

---

You may have wanted `(*ptr).set_value(true)` or `ptr->set_value(true)`. Either way would have worked, but `*ptr->set_value(true)` doesn't.